# Django readonly datetime field in inline causing naive datetime RuntimeWarning in tests

Tags: django

I'm getting this annoying error printed to the console when testing the admin add form. The `ProductAdmin` has an inline with a readonly datetime field which is the culprit of the error: `RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField Production.created_at received a naive datetime (2021-04-16 00:00:00) while time zone support is active.`

```
class ProductionInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = models.Production
    extra = 1
    fields = ('amount', 'details', 'created_by', 'created_at')
    readonly_fields = ('created_by', 'created_at')

@admin.register(models.Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (
        ProductImageInline,
        ProductionInline,
    )

def test_get_add(self):
    url = reverse('admin:product_product_add')
    response = self.client.get(url)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, HTTPStatus.OK)
```

The error is pretty self explanatory, I'm wondering if someone knows an easy way around this without setting a custom formset on the `TabularInline` that specifies a timezone aware initial value for the `created_at` field.

Interestingly this happens in the browser as well on initial page load after `./manage.py runserver` but subsequent page loads don't print the error.

Here's how the field is defined:

```
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I should also mention that `USE_TZ = True`.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this issue? I have `USE_TZ = True` same as you, with an inline model with the date time field same as you define. Is this only in tests or even when visiting the admin site yourself? What Django version do you use?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat weird, thanks for trying. I'm on 3.0.4. It happens in both the admin site and in tests. In the admin site it happens once then reloading the page doesn't print any warnings. The warning isn't printed when `extra = 0` on the inline.

Comment: Can't seem to find a ticket for this issue from version 3.0.4 (there is an issue but it is very old and fixed before 3.0) or find it as a bugfix in the release notes. If you have some custom form or something for the admin that may be the problem, else all I can suggest is trying to update or reinstall?